# How to make sure that MySQL app will work on client's PC even if MySQL isn't installed

Tags: mysql

I got windows application with MySQL database. Database will be stored on user's PC only. How to secure that my application will work on every Windows OS even if client doesn't have MySQL installed on his PC - how can I import mysql on user's PC if it's missing?

Comment: Have you considered SQLite? It's made for this sort of thing.

Comment: create an installer which calls the mysql installer before it tries to install the windows app and create the DB. Or, perhaps a saner approach would be to use a file-based DB like SqLite so you don't have the installation issue. or make the app connect to a central DB on a server (which is the conventional approach in most organiations - depends on the purpose and scope of the app I suppose).

Comment: Thank you. SQLite is not an option. My employer insists on MySQL

Comment: "My employer insists on MySQL"...because? Do they have an actual rationale for that in this case, or is it one of those arbitrary rules I often come across where people insist on a technology even when it's completely unsuitable for the task at hand just because "that's what we use" or some other similar nonsense. One of our skills as programmers is to make sure we use the right tool for the job. That decision should _not_ be taken by someone who's not a technology expert, or even by someone who may know something about tech but is far removed from the task actually being performed.

Comment: if someone is "insisting" on something, one responsibility of a programmer is to go back and explain why it's not actually a good idea and list all the problems it will cause. If you explain clearly and politely (but firmly), and then offer a ready-to-go alternative approach, you'll often find people are receptive, as you are presenting yourself as solving a problem for them, even if it's one they didn't know they had. We should just rigidly obey everything we are told, otherwise we won't truly add value to our products and organisations. Negotiate and innovate - it's how progress happens.

Comment: You cannot use a program that isn't available—that's universally true for every piece of software. If your actual question is how to bundle MySQL Server in your app installer, you'll need to provide specific details about target platform(s) and installer technology being used. (Said that, my gut feeling is that you could use SQLite under the hood and claim it's MySQL; whoever made such request is unlikely to notice.)

Comment: @vlad82 Most employers will at least *listen* to "I did a bunch of research and would like to propose a slightly different approach" if it's well thought out.

Answer (score 2):

You choose wrong approach. MySQL database is not suitable to be installed on each customer PC. There have many reasons to this. For example:

- customer PC too weak for run MySQL instance,
- or may be client PC already have installed MySQL,
- or one of thousands another reasons

You can choose MySQL only in client-server architecture: lightweight client application and server with MySQL stored all clients data. This approach demand stable network connection between client to server.

If you want to store all data locally on clients PC - [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) is right choose.

Comment: thanx, i'll try to change current solution